# wp-content directory files into an archive file named files.tar.gz

Tags: ssh, tar

I am trying  to put `wp-content` directory into an archive file named `files.tar.gz`. I am doing this through putty on the external sever where wordpress is placed.

After command:

```
tar -zcvf files.tar.gz /public_html/denim4u/wp-content
```

I receive:

> tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
>   tar:
>   /public_html/denim4u/wp-content: Cannot stat: No such file or
>   directory
>   tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The directory didn't exists ! Adapt path to file, please...

Comment: Mathieu thanks a lot easy thing, I have just putted end directory and it works

Comment: If I answer the question, you can accept it ?

Comment: Sorry, accept it?

Comment: Mark as solved !

Answer (score 0):

According to this error message :

> tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
>   tar: /public_html/denim4u/wp-content: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
>
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

The directory you want to compress is not a valid path.

Best regards